# How to setup my url route in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-state-provider

I am trying to capture a route to be something like

```
www.mysite.com/#name=ted&location=ca
```

I am using `stateprovider` and I setup as follow:

```
 $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
      url: '/#name',
      controller: function () {
         alert('here')
         do stuff...
      }
 })
```

but for some reason, alert never trigger.

Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ui-router or ngRoute ?

Comment: Could you please share all of the code that you have written till now?

Comment: @Sajeetharan ui.router

Comment: @PushkarKathuria really not much. One is setting the route and another one just pass url 'www.mysite.com/#name=ted&location=ca' to the app.

Comment: How are you making the transitions? Can you copy your code to plunker/codepen and share the url?

Comment: I believe that your # needs to be before the slash and Angular should put it there automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

To get params via query string you can use try:

```
 $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
      url: '/?name&location',
      controller: function () {
         alert('here')
         do stuff...
      }
 })
```

`#` will be there if HTML5 mode is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var app= angular.module('appName', []);

    app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'AddOrderController'
     }).
     when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/contact.html',
    controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
     }).
    otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
    });
    }]);
```

Try This Is Example Of Navigation Using With route Providers .

Answer (score 0):

When using ui.router, all routes need a template, include that in your state, remove the `#` sign from the URL and it should work